# NGINX Configuration for Multi-Tenant Application with Domain Mapping

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I'm developing a multi-tenant application with Laravel (PHP) as backend; and using NGINX as my web-server.

Aim: To allow each of my tenant to have their own subdomains; and also let them map their own subdomains or root domains using CNAME. Each subdomain / root domain will be served via HTTPS.

My NGINX Configuration -

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        charset utf-8;

        server_name *.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;   

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Above configuration works for any `<subdomain>.domain.com` that my users can create from the web UI of my application.

My aim is to let them point their CNAME records to their respective `<subdomain>.domain.com` and have a complete white-label solution that runs on their own domain.

Would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I do not see what is the problem here? Your application assigns a subdomain like `app-3b7ca83fc03.domain.com` - which of course is not pretty. So your customer goes into their domain registrar portal, opens the DNS editor and creates a CNAME which matches their own domain (e.g. `cars.bingo.adult`) to yours `app-3b7ca83fc03.domain.com`. When someone types `cars.bingo.adult` as URL in their browser - the browser will see the CNAME and perform a request to `app-3b7ca83fc03.domain.com` which will be happily handled by your nginX.

Comment: @IVOGELOV- the issue is that I'm unable to serve it via HTTPS. Also, If someone wants to map their main domain - would that look different? The main point is serving the sites via HTTPS.

Comment: Why not? You just need to know the CNAME in order to generate a certificate from LetsEncrypt - just like Netlify does it. The `server_name` in `nginx.conf` should contain both your subdomain and the corresponding CNAME.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - If I have https enabled - `https://test.domain.com` and user points their CNAME :  `check.userdomain.com` or simply `userdomain.com`  to ->  `test.domain.com`, should `https` work automatically for their domain? Or will I have to manually add server blocks to my NGINX configuration? Many companies have this done automatically ( I guess so! ).

Comment: CNAME happens on DNS level - so the URL in the browser will stay `check.userdomain.com` but the IP where the browser will connect is not the IP of `userdomain.com` - it is the IP of `test.domain.com`. So your nginX should have a corresponding `server` block and also you should serve a certificate which includes `check.userdomain.com`

Comment: @IVOGELOV - thanks for the clarification (and sorry for late response). It looks like I'll have to manually update server block in my NGINX configuration for each new mapped domain. Is there any way to automate this (without writing, maybe bash scripts?).

Comment: Since you need to generate a certificate for every client's domain - you can simply generate at the same time a `.conf` file containing the required `server` block and then simply put `include sites/*.conf` inside your `/etc/nginx.conf`. Then each time you create new conf file - simply reload nginX.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV - would you recommend using Caddyserver to achieve this in auto mode? It seems to be one of the top advertised features of Caddy.

Comment: I have not tried Caddy yet - the automatic SSL looks nice, I should take an eye someday ...